TLE on coin combinations 1 cses
can someone tell why the following code for coin combinations 1 question from cses problemset is getting time limit exceeded
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define int long long
using namespace std;
int MOD=1e9+7;
signed main()
{
    
    int n,x;
    cin>>n>>x;
    int nums[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>nums[i];
    }
    int dp[x+1]={0};
    dp[0]=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=x;i++){
        for(int q:nums){
            if(i-q>=0){
                dp[i]+=dp[i-q];
                dp[i]%=MOD;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<dp[x]<<endl; 
}


I tried changing the variable MOD from int MOD to const int MOD and it worked. i don't know what really changed in the code with it as i'm not changing the value of MOD anywhere.

To my understanding, the code does not change the value of MOD (as you already mentioned). However ,depending on the specific compiler used, the compiler might not be aware of this unless the declaration is changed to const. Hence, the compiler might apply optimizations which it didn't apply before.
